# How do I save images in a Mysql Database and seperate by date?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I save images in a Mysql Database? (and if possible seperate them by dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually discouraged to save files in Database. The suggested practice is Files in File-System and Data in Data-Base. : )

But if you have to, see this tutorial [Uploading Files To MySQL Database](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of pursuing this. The most common, and arguably efficient way , would be to save the files to the filesystem and store the paths in the database (and in your case a timestamp).

Alternatively, you can store the image as a `BLOB` in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table with id, image as a blob and a date. But I would not recommend it. It is better to save images as files and let your web server serve those. It'll help tremendously with performance, caching, etc